# Restrict records returned from nested LINQ statement

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

how would I restrict the "Charges" returned in this linq query, to a specified date range:

```
var dte  = DateTime.Parse("2012-01-01");
var dte2  = DateTime.Parse("2012-02-01");
var meetingrooms = tblMeetingRoom
        .Where(r => r.building_id==1)
        .GroupBy(p => p.tblType)
        .Select(g => new
            {
            TypeName = g.Key.room_type,
            TypeID = g.Key.type_id,
            TypeCount = g.Count(),
            charges =

                from rt in charges
                where (rt.type_id == g.Key.type_id)
                select new { 
                rt.chargedate,
                rt.people,
                rt.charge
                }
            });
            meetingrooms.Dump();
```

I think it needs to go inbetween here somehwhere:

```
from rt in charges
where (rt.type_id == g.Key.type_id) (EG) && rt.chargedate>=dte and rt.chargedate <dte2
select new {
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Why didn't you try the answer you gave before asking the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from rt in charges
where rt.type_id == g.Key.type_id && (rt.chargedate >= dte && rt.chargedate <= dte2)
select new {
      .....
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maarten - I've been trying this for ages - LinqPad kept giving errors, so I was trying all different ways I could think of - for whatever reason, I must have made some typos, that I didn't make above!

Sorry for wasting everyone's time - the above works "as-is"!

Mark